# Meaning of 'jiggelin' - word from the song 'Policeman' of Eva Simons

Tags: meaning, slang, songs

I can't find any definition about this word. Does anybody knows what does it mean? Maybe some kind of drugs?

Here are the [opening lines of the song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/evasimons/policeman.html) in question:

> Hey, mister policeman
>
> I don't want no trouble
>
> I just wanna drop my jiggelin' down to the floor
>
> Hey, mister policeman
>
> Why you wanna holla at me?
>
> I just wanna drop my jiggelin' down to the floor

According to the [Wikipedia article about her](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eva_Simons), Eva Simons "is a Dutch vocalist, songwriter and occasional actor," raised in Amsterdam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of total lack of context.

Comment: What if it were spelled "jiggling"?

Comment: @StevenLittman - There would still be a total lack of context.

Comment: No offense, Hot Licks, but I was addressing the OP, hoping to give a hint.

Comment: The context, of course, is to be found in the first stanzo (call you 'em 'stanzos'?) of Simons's song: "Hey, mister policeman/I don't want no trouble/I just wanna drop my jiggelin' down to the floor/Hey, mister policeman/Why you wanna holla at me?/I just wanna drop my jiggelin' down to the floor." The word is clearly slang, and the song provides no greater context regarding its intended meaning than in the lyrics I've quoted in this comment.

Comment: I wandered around Urban Dictionary a bit, and the best I could do is determine that a lot of "jiggle" words refer to various sexual acts and positions.  But I don't see how that fits the context very well.

Comment: @StevenLittman How can you drop a "jiggling"?

Comment: @Araucaria If you're dancing, partying, having a good time, jigglin' what your momma gave you, and a cop rolls up, maybe you'd feel inclined to drop said jigglers down on the floor, so as not to draw the attention or ire of the [one time](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=one%20time)?

Comment: It should be pointed out that interpreting obscure song lyrics is generally considered off-topic on EL&U.  (I can't for the life of me understand why some people voted to re-open the question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that *jiggelin'* is a contraction of "jiggling buttocks" - "jiggling" being similar in meaning to "wobbling".

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jiggling

```
 To move or rock lightly up and down or to and fro in an unsteady, jerky manner
```

So, the speaker is saying that she simply wants to lower her jiggling backside (or perhaps her jiggling body as a whole) towards the floor (eg the dance floor of a nightclub), presumably as a **dance move** - ie, that she simply wants to go dancing.

She is finding the conversation with the policeman frustrating, as it is preventing her from reaching the aforementioned night club, where she can proceed with the "jiggelin'".